# Render Angular Material Component in Server

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I have a task where I need to render a select tag in the server and send it to Angular client. I would like to also apply Angular Material style to it. When generating a normal  tag, it is rendered correctly.
However, when using mat-select it does display the response as a plain text, without applying styles or anything.
I already bypassed the security warning that Angular displays concerning sanitizing the response so this is not the problem.

**insert.service.ts:** *(service to get response from server)*

```
getFamilies() {
    return this.http.get(this.familyUrl, { responseType: 'text' });
  }
```

**insert.components.ts:**

```
html: any;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getFamilies();
  }
getFamilies() {
    this.insertService.getFamilies().subscribe((response) => {
      this.html = response;
    });
  }
```

**insert.component.html:** *(html file where the response needs to be displayed)*

```
<div class="flex justify-start items-center px-6" [innerHTML]="html | families"> </div>
```

Note that 'families' is the name of the pipe that is used to bypass the security of html (**bypassSecurityTrustHtml()** function).

**What can be a solution?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Style is not applied after sanitization and \[innerHTML\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63610520/style-is-not-applied-after-sanitization-and-innerhtml)

Comment: @Zze No, this solution did not solve my problem.